# How to use functions in the jar package?

Tags: java

I'm a Java beginner. I imported the jar package but I can't import it. I also wonder why the jar package is yellow and why is it automatically undone if I paste the import on top of the main class? Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSmzt.png)

I can't understand it.
the question is algs4.jar

Comment: [Edit] your question and post the text of the import that you are trying to add. I see three JAR files in the image linked to in your question: `algs4.jar`, `introcs.jar` and `stdlib.jar`. Which JAR are you referring to?

Comment: Take a look at package managers like Apache Maven.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely ！！！，I I reloaded the jar package  to solve  this problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to your project library.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).